# ¿Como limitar el numero de caracteres del metadescription de una entrada en Wordpress?

Tags: php, css3, wordpress

estoy construyendo un proyecto y quiero delimitar el numero de caracteres que se muestran en el PREVIEW del POST en una búsqueda de Wordpress, Adjunto imagen con el text que deseo delimitar, **es el texto seleccionado**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El texto con el que intente delimitar esto y **no funciono**, es el siguiente:

```
function get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace(" ([.*?])",'',$excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 50);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">more</a>';
return $excerpt;
}

function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Answer (score 2):

La función **wp_trim_words()** recorta un texto.

> wp_trim_words( string $text, int $num_words = 55, string $more = null )
>
> Parámetros:
>
> **$texto** ( string ) (*Requerido*) Texto para recortar.
>
> **$num_words** ( int ) (*Opcional*) Número de palabras.
>     Valor por defecto: 55
>
> **$more** ( string ) (*Opcional*) Qué anexar si se debe recortar $ text.
>     Defecto '…'.
>     Valor por defecto: nulo

Fuente: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/